# Ruby on Rails (Michael Hart Tutorial) authorization error (chapter 9.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authorization

I am learning Ruby on Rails from Michael Hartl's tutorials.
And now I'm stuck at chapter 9.2.1.
Here is the code in the book:

authentication_pages_spec.erb
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { sign_in user }

    it { should have_title(user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

    describe "followed by signout" do
      before { click_link "Sign out" }
      it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
  end
  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I test:

```
rspec spec/
```

there are 2 errors that I don't know how to fix at line:

```
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
```

and line:

```
specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
```

Here is the error image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/85WaX.png

Comment: What are these errors?

Comment: Oops, sorry!
Here is the image.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/85WaX.png

Answer (score 0):

You missed `before { sign_in user }` inside  `describe "visiting the edit page" do` block.

But you have used that correctly for other blocks, like:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }
```